# Why does XSLT output all text by default?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Hi I had performed a transformation which drops a tag if it is null.

I wanted to check whether my transformation is working fine, so instead of checking it manually, I wrote one more XSLT code which just checks the presence of that particular tag in the OUTPUT XML, if it is null, then the second XSLT should output a text "FOUND". (I don't actually need some XML kind of output but I am just using XSLT for searching.)

When I tried with this XSL code ::

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/SiebelMessage//SuppressCalendar[.!='']">
      FOUND
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It outputs all the TEXT DATA that is present in the XML file,

to avoid that, I had to write this code::

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/SiebelMessage//SuppressCalendar[.!='']">
      FOUND
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

why did the former code outputs TEXT, why should I insist XSL to ignore all other text? is that the behavior of all XML parsers or only of my own (I am using msxml parser).

Answer (score 155, accepted):

> why did the former code outputs TEXT,
> why should I insist XSL to ignore all
> other text? is that the behavior of
> all XML parsers or only of my own

**You are discovering one of the most fundamental XSLT features as specified in the Specification: the [built-in templates of XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#built-in-rule)**.

**From [the Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#built-in-rule)**:

> There is a built-in template rule to
> allow recursive processing to continue
> in the absence of a successful pattern
> match by an explicit template rule in
> the stylesheet. This template rule
> applies to both element nodes and the
> root node. The following shows the
> equivalent of the built-in template
> rule:
>
> ```
> <xsl:template match="*|/">
>   <xsl:apply-templates/>
> </xsl:template>
> ```
>
> There is also a built-in template rule
> for each mode, which allows recursive
> processing to continue in the same
> mode in the absence of a successful
> pattern match by an explicit template
> rule in the stylesheet. This template
> rule applies to both element nodes and
> the root node. The following shows the
> equivalent of the built-in template
> rule for mode m.
>
> ```
> <xsl:template match="*|/" mode="m">
>   <xsl:apply-templates mode="m"/>
> </xsl:template>
> ```
>
> There is also a built-in template rule
> for text and attribute nodes that
> copies text through:
>
> ```
> <xsl:template match="text()|@*">
>   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
> </xsl:template>
> ```
>
> The built-in template rule for
> processing instructions and comments
> is to do nothing.
>
> ```
> <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()|comment()"/>
> ```
>
> The built-in template rule for
> namespace nodes is also to do nothing.
> There is no pattern that can match a
> namespace node; so, the built-in
> template rule is the only template
> rule that is applied for namespace
> nodes.
>
> The built-in template rules are
> treated as if they were imported
> implicitly before the stylesheet and
> so have lower import precedence than
> all other template rules. Thus, the
> author can override a built-in
> template rule by including an explicit
> template rule.

So, the reported behavior is the result of the application of the built-in templates -- the 1st and 2nd of all three of them.

**It is a good XSLT design pattern to override the built-in templates** with your own that will issue an error message whenever called so that the programmer immediately knows his transformation is "leaking":

**For example**, if there is this XML document:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>Don't want to see this</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

**and it is processed with this transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 
 <xsl:template match="a|b">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**the result is**:

```
<a name="a">
   <b name="b">Don't want to see this</b>
</a>
```

and the programmer will be greatly confused how the unwanted text appeared.

**However, just adding this *`catch-all template`* helps avoid any such confusion and catch errors immediately**:

```
 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:message terminate="no">
   WARNING: Unmatched element: <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
  </xsl:message>
  
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
```

**Now, besides the confusing output the programmer gets a warning that explains the problem immediately**:

```
 WARNING: Unmatched element: c
```

**Later Addition by Michael Kay for XSLT 3.0**

In XSLT 3.0, rather than adding a catch-all template rule, you can specify the fallback behaviour on an `xsl:mode` declaration. For example, `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>` causes all nodes that are not matched (including text nodes) to be skipped, while `<xsl:mode on-no-match="fail"/>` treats a no-match as an error, and `<xsl:mode warning-on-no-match="true"/>` results in a warning.

Comment: +1: Great explanation - much more complete than the accepted answer, though the accepted answer does also answer the specific question.

Comment: @donroby: Thanks. Why would my answer not address the question and answer it?. Anybody having this problem and reading my answer will understand the cause of their problem and will be able to fix it.

Comment: @donroby: My reply provides an exact answer: `"So, the reported behavior is the result of the application of the built-in templates -- the 2nd of all three of them"`

Comment: Yes, your reply does also answer the specific question.  Didn't intend to imply otherwise.  The intent was to not  specifically deprecate the accepted answer.

I do in fact prefer your answer though.

Comment: @ZacharyYoung, Sorry, I don't understand the question. If you mean why not all possible elements from the source XML document are matched (and also text nodes), this is for this example to have an unmatched element.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, in my case I don't get values of attributes in the output, only leaf text elements. I can't figure out why, cause according to the specification, attribute values should be also written.

Comment: @damluar, This is simple: The built-in templates never apply templates on attribute nodes. If a template is never applied, it is not selected for execution. So, the built-in template matching any attribute node is never selected for execution.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, the first default template calls `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, so I assumed it says "apply templates to subelements, attributes, etc". And since we have second template `<xsl:template match="text()|@*">` and it matches attributes, I expected to get attribute texts. Which of my assumptions is false?

Comment: @damular: Actually no, `<xsl:apply-templates/>` is a shorthand for `<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>`  and attributes are not children -- they just *belong* to an element.

Comment: I'm trying this out and both <xsl:message> doesn't seem to display anything, and <xsl:apply-templates/> seems to them pick up the thing I'm trying to hide! In Firefox 28.0. Any ideas, or is this a whole other question to ask? :-)

Comment: @Rikki, Firefox isn't an XSLT processor at all. Please, use a normal XSLT processor. The details how an `<xsl:message>` is displayed vary from processor to processor. You need to read them in the documentation of your XSLT processor.

Comment: It does a reasonable job, is accessible and if the output of the transformation is HTML, then it makes complete sense! Got any recommendations for a "normal" XSLT processor?

Comment: @Rikki, Of course: If XSLT 1, one could use MSXML (3, 4 or 6) or the .NET XslCompiledTransform, or Saxon 6.5.x -- all of these have their own command-line utility to execute them. If XSLT 2 or greater, then I usually recommend Saxon 9.x.

Comment: Where can I find an explanation of how to use `<xsl:mode on-no-match="fail"/>`? If I just put that in my XSLT document, I can't even match the input XML document node; see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76347947) about this.

Comment: @GarretWilson, I answered your SO question. Please do let me know if you need any further help.

Answer (score 14):

There are several [built in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) in XSL, one of which is this:

```
<xsl:template match="text()|@*">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

It outputs text.

Comment: thanks, so is it specific to the particular parser, or in general?

Comment: I guess, its general rule for all parsers 'coz its w3c specification. alright, thanks :)

Comment: @infant programmer - it is in the spec, as you have noted... all XSL parsers have to implement them.

Comment: That particular built-in rule escapes [special XML characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents), i.e. it rewrites `&amp;` in the original text to `&amp;amp;` in the output. To avoid that, add `disable-output-escaping="yes"` as an attribute to the `<xsl:value-of>` element.