# I can't select a node value from a namespaced XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, namespaces, xslt-1.0

I'm having trouble transforming a SOAP response XML into a plain text string.
I'm starting with XLST and I've read all I could about. Apparently what I need to accomplish is simple, but all examples are way simpler than my context.

First, I'm reaching a web service (Bing Maps Reverse Geocoding) that returns this XML structure:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <ReverseGeocodeResponse xmlns="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocode/contracts">
      <ReverseGeocodeResult xmlns:a="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocode" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <BrandLogoUri xmlns="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/common">
          http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png
        </BrandLogoUri>
        <ResponseSummary xmlns="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/common">
          <AuthenticationResultCode>ValidCredentials</AuthenticationResultCode>
          <Copyright>(...)</Copyright>
          <FaultReason i:nil="true" />
          <StatusCode>Success</StatusCode>
          <TraceId>(...)</TraceId>
        </ResponseSummary>
        <a:Results xmlns:b="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/common">
          <b:GeocodeResult>
            <b:Address>
              <b:AddressLine>(...)</b:AddressLine>
              <b:AdminDistrict>SP</b:AdminDistrict>
              <b:CountryRegion>Brasil</b:CountryRegion>
              <b:District />
              <b:FormattedAddress>(...)</b:FormattedAddress>
              <b:Locality>Campinas</b:Locality>
              <b:PostalCode>13069-380</b:PostalCode>
              <b:PostalTown />
            </b:Address>
            <b:BestView>(...)</b:BestView>
            <b:Confidence>Medium</b:Confidence>
            <b:DisplayName>(...)</b:DisplayName>
            <b:EntityType>Address</b:EntityType>
            <b:Locations>(...)</b:Locations>
            <b:MatchCodes xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
              <c:string>Good</c:string>
            </b:MatchCodes>
          </b:GeocodeResult>
          <b:GeocodeResult>
            (...)
          </b:GeocodeResult>
        </a:Results>
      </ReverseGeocodeResult>
    </ReverseGeocodeResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The node `b:GeocodeResult` is repeated about 10 times. The other parts with `(...)` are irrelevant (no related nodes).
The only thing I need from this extensive response are the nodes `b:Locality` and `b:AdminDistrict`.
I'm struggling for the last couple days to get this done.

Here's one of the many approaches:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/common"
        xmlns:a="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocode"
        xmlns:b="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/common"
        xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
        xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:template match="/s:Envelope/s:Body/ReverseGeocodeResponse/ReverseGeocodeResult/a:Results/b:GeocodeResult/b:Address">
        <xsl:value-of select="b:Locality"/> - <xsl:value-of select="b:AdminDistrict"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I know this should only return the first `b:Locality` and `b:AdminDistrict` nodes, and that's perfect. But when I try this, the result is all the text in the XML (no tags at all, just concatenated text). Some variations of this approach return only the ' - ' fragment between the two `xsl:value-of` tags.

What am I doing wrong? Can this be related to the infinity of namespaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What *is* happening in your stylesheet**

What happens in your original code is this: The one template you have written does *not* match anything in the input XML. This means that the code inside this template is never executed. Instead, for all nodes in the input XML, the default, [*built-in templates* are applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360017/why-does-xslt-output-all-text-by-default).

The built-in templates traverse through the tree and do not output anything else than all the text content. That is why you end up with:

> But when I try this, the result is all the text in the XML (no tags at all, just concatenated text).

To prevent this, write an empty template that matches all text:

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

Then, you immediately and more clearly see the difference between your template not being applied at all (no output) and of it giving the wrong result (wrong output).

**Why is this happening in your stylesheet?**

The template does not match anything because your path expression:

```
/s:Envelope/s:Body/ReverseGeocodeResponse/ReverseGeocodeResult/a:Results/b:GeocodeResult/b:Address"
```

does not match any node in the input XML. For the path expression above, an XPath processor expects that the `ReverseGeocodeResponse` and `ReverseGeocodeResult`are in *no* namespace. But for your input XML, that's not true:

```
<ReverseGeocodeResponse xmlns="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocode/contracts">
    <ReverseGeocodeResult xmlns:a="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocode">
```

On the `ReverseGeocodeResponse` element, there is a *default namespace* - that in this case also applies to this element itself. Also, it causes its child element `ReverseGeocodeResult` to take on this namespace.

**A solution to this**

Declare this namespace (`http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocode/contracts`) in your XSLT stylesheet and prefix the two elements that have it. I know you tried to mimick the input XML's default namespace with:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/common">
```

but the effect is different. This defines a default namespace for *elements* in the XSLT stylesheet. But what you wanted to do is define an default namespace for XPath expressions. That's also possible with [`xpath-default-namespace`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unprefixed-qnames) - which

- is only available in XSLT 2.0 unfortunately
- is not useful because your input XML has *more than one* default namespace

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:a="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocode"
        xmlns:b="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/common"
        xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
        xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:con="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocode/contracts">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/s:Envelope/s:Body/con:ReverseGeocodeResponse/con:ReverseGeocodeResult/a:Results/b:GeocodeResult/b:Address">
        <xsl:value-of select="b:Locality"/> - <xsl:value-of select="b:AdminDistrict"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Text Output**

```
Campinas - SP
```

Comment: That's perfect! Already tested it and it works great! Thanks a lot, I'll read through your answer and try to understand the details, but the stylesheet you provided works exactly as needed.

Comment: @PauloAvelar You're welcome. I'd appreciate if you read the details - they took a lot of time :-).

Answer (score 1):

The `jumble` of xml you are seeing is due to the [default processing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360017/why-does-xslt-output-all-text-by-default) of the built-in templates. Typically, if you only want to process specific elements in the document, you'll want to capture the root element, and then use `apply-templates` selectively.

Also, the reason why you aren't seeing the expected values is because `ReverseGeocodeResponse` and `ReverseGeocodeResult` are actually xmlns namespace `http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocode/contracts` - you'll need to adjust your xslt appropriately (I've added alias `zz`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/common"
        xmlns:a="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocode"
        xmlns:b="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/common"
        xmlns:c="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
        xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:zz="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocode/contracts">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/s:Envelope/s:Body/zz:ReverseGeocodeResponse/zz:ReverseGeocodeResult/a:Results/b:GeocodeResult/b:Address"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="b:Address">
    <xsl:value-of select="b:Locality"/> - <xsl:value-of select="b:AdminDistrict"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```