# Why does my XSL strip out all the tags?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this inbound XML (as a web service) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Envelope>
    <Body>
        <send_message>
            <user>
                <now>2017-11-17T13:38:11+00:00</now>
                <company>xyz.demo</company>
            </user>
            <messages>
                <message>
                    <app_host>app102.example.com</app_host>
                    <app_port>31632</app_port>
.....
```

and I'm executing this XSL against it:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

<xsl:template match="//Envelope/Body/send_message/user/now">
  <now>
    <xsl:variable name="srcDateTime" select="//Envelope/Body/send_message/user/now"/>
    <xsl:variable name="srcDate" select="substring-before($srcDateTime, 'T')" />
    <xsl:variable name="outDate" select="format-date(xs:date($srcDate),'[D01].[M01].[Y0001]')"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$outDate"/>
  </now>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My intention is to reformat the date in the `<now></now` tags - which it does perfectly - but it also strips out all the other tags from the XML, when I need them in so I can extract data using XPath in further manipulation steps. This is what the result looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>



                <now xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">17.11.2017</now>
                xyz.demo


                    app102.example.com
                    31632

 .....
```

You can see that all the other tags have been completely stripped away (just leaving white space behind), and I just don't understand why that's happening. What am I missing (other than the tags!)?

To further explain - these missing tags aren't null, they have data in them. As you can see, from the result I posted, the data is still there, but the enclosing tags are missing. I need the data back in the original enclosing tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does XSLT output all text by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360017/why-does-xslt-output-all-text-by-default)

Comment: Start from an identity transform that does not change anything, and add your new template there. Also, the template match can simply be `now` instead of an absolute path expression.

Comment: To further explain - these missing tags aren't null, they have data in them. As you can see, from the result I posted, the data is still there, but the enclosing tags are missing. I need the data back in the original enclosing tags.

Comment: @MathiasMüller - I don't know what you mean about "Start from an identity transform that does not change anything" - I'm a complete noob to XSLT, and trying to learn via the necessity of having to do it. I've adjusted the absolte path, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your XML unmodified except for `<now>`, you just need to add an identity transform:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Your other template will override it only on the nodes corresponding to the specified xpath `//Envelope/Body/send_message/user/now`.

(edit: As Martin Müller pointed out, you should consider to reduce that absolute path to the necessary relative path, depending on your usecase, e.g. simply `now` or, if you need to limit the scope of the expression, `user/now`.)

Comment: I love you! Completely fixed, providing just what I needed (explanation AND a solution). Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you should also point out to the OP that a stylesheet with absolute path expressions as template matches is bad style. Please amend your answer to make it clear that `<xsl:template match="now">` is the right form of the template.

Comment: I would not say "right" or "bad style", however I totally agree on limiting the xpath expression to what is necessary in the usecase (of which OP showed only a portion).