# Joint map test output contains data outside tags

Tags: xml, xslt, biztalk

I am in the process of creating a joint map from two different maps, using the same source schema.

In the joint map I've set up the logic to execute the correct one of the two maps, based on a subtype in the source schema, using a template match:

```
<xsl:template match="//Header[contains(InvoiceType,'Invoice')]">
```

This all works well and good, but when I test the map, I receive invalid XML. My line element seems to be created twice, one correctly inside the XML tags, and another one outside the tags, at the end of the document.

```
<E1EDP01>
            <POSEX>1</POSEX>
            <MENGE>2</MENGE>
            <E1EDP19>
                <QUALF>002</QUALF>
                <IDTNR>000000000000000000</IDTNR>
                <KTEXT>Paysafecard 100 DKR</KTEXT>
                <MFRPN/>
                <MFRNR/>
                <IDTNR_EXTERNAL>9120005810976</IDTNR_EXTERNAL>
            </E1EDP19>
            <E1EDP19>
                <QUALF>003</QUALF>
                <IDTNR>9120005810976</IDTNR>
                <KTEXT/>
                <MFRPN/>
                <MFRNR/>
                <IDTNR_EXTERNAL/>
            </E1EDP19>
        </E1EDP01>

0

        9120005810976
        9120005810976

      2
      EA
      Paysafecard 100 DKR


        100.00
        0
        0.00
        200.00
        0.00
```

I can't figure out why this happens, as the rest of the elements are showing just fine. This occurs in both maps.

To generate the lines output, I am using an xsl:for-each:

```
<xsl:for-each select="../Lines">
          <xsl:for-each select="Line">
```

The Lines element is on the same level as the Header element.

Any hint as to what could cause this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should share the complete xslt as well , and piece of xml code that you are trying to transform, what i understand from this, you are selecting values more than once , as you are using for-each and ../ line they are meant to choose "all" in your file , so you need to find the path once, or for-each is just enogh to get both.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360017/why-does-xslt-output-all-text-by-default. This is because of built-in default templates. You have to overwrite them to avoid such "effects"

Comment: Sorry, I have to remind that this is not a path you should pursue as it's making the app **much more complicated** than it needs to be and causing **problems for future developers**.  Where are these messages going?