# Creating a csv File Header Row with XSL

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, header

I am new to XSL and am trying to create a text csv header row with the code below. All I get is the content of each StartTime tag. What am I missing?

```
<xsl:stylesheet
version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />

    <xsl:variable name="headers">
        <xsl:call-template name="do_header">
            <xsl:with-param name="headers" select="//Event//@channel[not(.=../../preceding-sibling::Event//@channel)]" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
<!-- Write the Header -->

    <xsl:template name="do_header">
        <xsl:param name="headers" />
        <xsl:text>Time,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="$headers">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Program>
   <Event>
      <StartTime units="us">5</StartTime>
      <LaserOn channel="HeNe Laser" />
   </Event>
   <Event>
      <StartTime units="us">15</StartTime>
      <LaserOff channel="HeNe Laser" />
   </Event>
   <Event>
      <StartTime units="us">55</StartTime>
      <LaserOn channel="HeNe Laser" />
      <LaserOn channel="TiSaph" />
   </Event>
   <Event>
      <StartTime units="us">125</StartTime>
      <LaserOff channel="TiSaph" />
   </Event>
   <Event>
      <StartTime units="us">905</StartTime>
      <LaserOn channel="HeNe Laser" />
      <LaserOn channel="TiSaph" />
   </Event>
   <Event>
      <StartTime units="us">1500</StartTime>
      <LaserOff channel="HeNe Laser" />
   </Event>
</Program>
```

[Output of the xslt. It only output the content of the StartTime tags ie. 5 15 55 125 905 1500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLAth.png)

Comment: In addition to the answer provided below by Mads Hansen, do note that this is not a good method to generate unique values - read here why: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Answer (score 1):

You have created a variable `$header` and a named template that is used to generate headers, but you haven't created any other templates that would match any content and use the `$header`.

Therefore, the [default processing occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3378562/14419), which is the equivalent of matching on elements and applying templates to children nodes, and a template matching `text()` that returns it. So, if you apply an XSLT without matching any templates that would do something different, you just generate output with all of the `text()`.

You would generate the same output if your stylesheet were just:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, in order to generate your header, you could create a template that matches on the root node `/` and then return the value of the `$header` variable, which has the headers produced by calling that `do_header` named template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />
    
    <xsl:variable name="headers">
        <xsl:call-template name="do_header">
            <xsl:with-param name="headers" select="//Event//@channel[not(.=../../preceding-sibling::Event//@channel)]" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <!-- Write the Header -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="$headers"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="do_header">
        <xsl:param name="headers" />
        <xsl:text>Time,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="$headers">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could also just call that `do_header` template and avoid creating the variable:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />
        
    <!-- Write the Header -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="do_header">
            <xsl:with-param name="headers" select="//Event//@channel[not(.=../../preceding-sibling::Event//@channel)]" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="do_header">
        <xsl:param name="headers" />
        <xsl:text>Time,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="$headers">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you. Very clear explanation. On both modifications, the output was missing a comma after the HeNE header text ie. Time,HeNe Laser,TiSaph, . Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by missing a comma after "HeNe" header text. There is an entry for "HeNe Laser" and it is followed by a comma.

Comment: My error. Thank you again!